# Rotate Left and Right Not Working as Expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, transform

I have a div which I have added two spans and a button, these spans are to rotate the div left and rotate it right.
The right span is called rotate right and the left span is called rotate left, these are children of a parent div called table.

```
<div id="table1" class="table square4 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" +="" style="inset:69px auto auto 445px;">
    <div class="removet"></div>
    <span class="fa fa-edit editdiv"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-rotate-left rotateleft"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-rotate-right rotateright"></span>
</div>
```

This results in the following div.

[image]

Here is the CSS for the table as well, just incase the css for the Table is clashing with my Transform statement.

```
.square4 {
  cursor: move;
  width: 133px;
  height: 133px;
  position: absolute !important;
  background-image: url(parts/table4.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00f;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6%;
  -moz-border-radius: 6%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6%;
  left: 741px;
  top: -141px;
}
```

When the user clicks left or right the parent div should get rotate by 15 degrees, however when i click rotate right nothing happens, and when i click rotate left it sets the degrees to rotate 0, which is the first vlaue and not the value that I need. I have my values set into an Array from 0 to 360 degrees, they go up by 15 degrees each time rotate right is clicked or go back 15 degrees if the rotate left is clicked.

The div's are appended to a droppable element called mainarea, using JQuery UI, which is why i am using a .on click. The click is detected, its just the transform I am having the issue with.

I have checked the Array and the button clicks to make sure they are working, I have used console.log to check angle[current] and the correct values are returned, I believe it has something to do with my transform statement and how i am setting it, i have tried different ways and had no luck.

I am using Elementor so my document.ready is a bit different than the usual way, but this is beacuse of the way Elementor works, if you wish to test it you can just change this to a document ready statement instead, but I wanted to show my exact code.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 
{
    var angle = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315 , 330, 345, 360];
    var current = 0;

   jQuery(document).on('click','.table > .rotateright',function(event)
    {
       current++;

        if(current == 25)
        {
            current = 0;
        }

       var r = jQuery(this).parents('.table').attr('id');

       var rotating = '#'.concat(r);

       console.log(angle[current]);

       jQuery(rotating).css({
          '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-moz-transform'    : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-ms-transform'     : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-o-transform'      : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          'transform'         : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')'
        });
   });

    jQuery(document).on('click','.table > .rotateleft',function(event)
    {
        current--;

        if(current == -1)
        {
            current = 24;
        }

       var r = jQuery(this).parents('.table').attr('id');

       var rotating = '#'.concat(r);

        console.log(angle[current]);

       jQuery(rotating).css({
          '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-moz-transform'    : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-ms-transform'     : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          '-o-transform'      : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')',
          'transform'         : 'rotate(' + angle[current] + ')'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a working demo snippet, not able to reproduce snippet with the above code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53rajoky/1/

Comment: I literally mean a working fiddle, not copy paste codes :)

Comment: Its not working so how can i make a working fiddle? If it doesnt work for me and i am asking for help all i can do is put the code in i have already put here.

Comment: even the fiddle is not running, nothing is visible, us to do this for you, or fix the bug for you ??

Comment: Strange as i checked the fiddle, i dont need you to do this for me, i am just needing some help to find out what the bug us.

Comment: I will have a look at the fiddle later and send the working one with the bug, sorry i tried to do on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the 'deg' ('+ angle[current]+' deg) in the CSS while assigning the new rotating CSS

I have modified the code for right rotate only (I didnt changed code for left, can change like right), here [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0ntq5uv/)

Small snipet is as below

```
 $('#table1').css({
               ' -webkit-transform': 'rotate('+ angle[current]+' deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+ angle[current]+' deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate('+ angle[current]+'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+ angle[current]+'deg)',
                  'transform': 'rotate('+ angle[current]+'deg)'}
    );
```

and the right span keep it outside the target div as it will rotate as the main div rotate

Comment: Omg that is it, how did i not notice that, the statement was fine once i put the deg statement in.

Comment: I have voted your answer, thank you so much, this is what happens when you code at midnight haha

Comment: @JayDJohno haha, you welcome also you can accept this answer, happy coding